# attr_encryptor bad decrypt error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-encrypted

I used danpal/attr_encryptor gem to encrypt some attribute in my ActiveRecord model.

```
attr_encrypted :number, :charset => 'UTF-8', :key => 'vasya pupkin'
```

and got following error

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt
```

Then I tried to use encrypt_number in rails console and seen different values for the same value of 'number' field when I restarted console. Why?

```
rails c
CreditCard.encrypt_number('hello')
"tRO0BETHrh5J3gXv8WVntw==\n"
quit
rails c
CreditCard.encrypt_number('hello')
"kJSbe30RQyR+gy3oDXv5ZA==\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the bad decrypt error, have you created `encrypted_number_iv` and `encrypted_number_salt` columns in your database and is the gem populating them for you automatically?

In the case of `encrypt_number`, you need to pass `:iv` and `:salt` options (the same each time) to receive the same ciphertext at the output.